# openFrameworks vs Processing

Tags: processing, openframeworks

I have been reading a lot about  openFrameworks and Processing, But still can't make the distinction other than one is in C++ and the other in Java. Can someone tell me which is for what exactly?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You are correct, one is C++ and the other is Java, and those differences apply to these frameworks, so it's up to your preferences/project scope to decide which one is best for you.

[image: processing header]

With **Processing**:

- You get a minimal IDE, but can [easily use Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) or other Java IDEs.
- You get memory management (garbage collection)
- You can publish applets online(via Java Applet or 'slimmed down' javascript ports using Canvas 2D with [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/) or [p5js](http://p5js.org/)) or desktop applications for Linux/OSX/Windows (via Java Runtime). Note that versions newer than  Processing 1.5.1 no longer export applets. That can still be done via command line or using eclipse.
- You can publish to [Android](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android) and (with 3rd party tools) to iPhone using [iProcessing](http://www.luckybite.com/iprocessing/) or the faster [P5Nitro](https://github.com/davidedc/P5Nitro) and more recently on [Raspberry PI](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Raspberry-Pi)
- You get almost 200 [Libraries](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/) to extend its functionality.
- You have support from [the forums](http://discourse.processing.org/), quite a few [books](http://processing.org/learning/books/) and online 'playgrounds' like [OpenProcessing](http://openprocessing.org/), [SketchPatch](http://sketchpatch.net/), [hascanvas](http://www.hascanvas.com/) or [SketchPad](http://sketchpad.cc/).

[image: OpenFrameworks logo]

With **OpenFrameworks**:

- You choose your IDE (XCode on OSX, Code::Blocks, VC++)
- You can manage your own memory (malloc, pointers and all that joy), but with modern C++ it's not necessary.
- You can publish your project as a native application (no runtime needed)
- <strike>You can **not** currently easily publish online, but this might change in the future(see [Arturo Castro's of-emscripten](http://arturocastro.net/files/of-emscripten/) progress)</strike>You **can** publish online using [emscripten](https://openframeworks.cc/setup/emscripten/).
- You can publish to the [iPhone](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/iphone), as of [OF 007](http://www.openframeworks.cc/download) to [Android](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/android-eclipse) and OF 0.8.0 to armv6 and armv7 devices such as [Raspberry PI](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/) or [Pandaboard](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/pandaboard/)
- You get over 2000 [Addons](http://ofxaddons.com/categories) (not all are maintained) to extend its functionality.
- You have support from the [very active and helpful forums](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/) and can read about it in this [online book](http://openframeworks.cc/ofBook/chapters/foreword.html) or on a paper [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021735.do) or [two](https://www.packtpub.com/mastering-openframeworks-creative-coding-demystified/book).

These are some of the things the came to mind right now, there could be more.

Personally, I found it easier to write really basic throw-away prototypes in Processing. For situations where speed isn't a major decision factor, Processing does just well, but in other cases, I'd port the Processing prototypes to openFrameworks (which is easy to do most of the time).

An example would be application involving audio, be it analysis or synthesis. Depending on the complexity, the Java Garbage Collector would do a sweep when you least expect it and cause annoyances when you need responsiveness.

In short, both are really cool, but **openFrameworks** is **faster**. You pay for that speed by **managing memory** yourself though.

In terms of deploying online, it really depends on the project: if it's a simple project, probably p5.js might be easiest  in terms of integration with other js libraries. The oF export is handy for big bulky complex code that would take too long to manually port to JavaScript, but bare in mind the Emscripten project will be large (e.g. 17.5MB for `opencvExample`) (and thus not cellular friendly) and you will still need to add your own [JS -> C++](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-binding-cpp) bindings if your need to call oF app function from the webpage.

Also, if you're interested in C++, you might want to also have a look at [libcinder](http://libcinder.org/) or [Polycode](http://polycode.org/).

HTH

Comment: you can deploy OF on an Android Device, too!

Comment: Just as an update to this question, it looks like with the new version of Processing (2.0a7) it won't be possible to publish applets anymore. There is more info here http://blog.openprocessing.org/?p=232

Comment: But you can still make applets through using Processing with Eclipse

Comment: Great analysis. I was wondering the same thing and drew similar conclusions. I think this confirms it.

Comment: You can deploy OF on web browsers using Emscripten.
https://openframeworks.cc/setup/emscripten/

Comment: @ZackLee Thanks for the heads-up: I've updated the answer to include the link you provided

Comment: "You manage your own memory(malloc, pointers and all that joy)" - I think that's no longer true. With C++11 and newer, I never had to call new, delete, malloc nor used raw pointers. I used smart pointers, std::vector instead of array, std::string instead of cstring... not that different from Processing.