# What is the difference between OpenCV, OpenFramework and Processing Frameworks?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, openframeworks

I want to start my project for live video content analysis, Face Detection, Gesture Detection and Gaze Tracking.

Here i am unable to find the right framework for me.  I am well versed with C++, JAVA, and Python.  But i Prefer C++.

Can anybody suggest me whats the best among the following frameworks.

1. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
2. [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/)
3. [Processing](http://processing.org/)

Please, also suggest me the book/tutorial/videos

Thanks

Comment: OpenCV is a library for computer vision(image/video processing, feature detection/extraction, stereo vision, etc.).You can use it with C++/Java/C/Python out of the box but there are wrapper for other languages too. Processing and OpenFrameworks are very similar in their goal: simplify development for artists/designers, but different by syntax: Processing (mainly) is a Java library, but there are javascript/python ports supported officially. You can find out more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291769/open-framework-v-s-processing/5291934#5291934)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three frameworks you posted here are totally different!

So,

OpenCV is a collection of algorithms for computer vision. Sounds good for you.

OpenFrameworks is a tool that help you manage video content - read, write, stream multimedia. It can help you if the default OpenCV functions do not allow you to read the video you want to process. But in the first stages of your project, it's better to focus on algorithms.

And what is Processing frameworks? a new lib? or just a reference to all the video libraries out there?

Comment: would be good to provide a link to their site. Googling for processing frameworks is just a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Processing is Java script built on c and c++ libraries. Its a self contained IDE.

Openframeworks is a collection of libraries that mimics the natural language use of processing but  entirely c++ that you use in something like visual basic or xcode.

Opencv is camera vision that has been ported to processing and of.

Examples are included with of for cv.

Also, processing.org and openframeworks.cc are great references.